# Using Kotlin code transpiled to JavaScript in an Angular/client-side project

Tags: javascript, angular, kotlin

We have a Kotlin project for which some classes are intended to be shared with the client-side, and as a result have configured our `kotlin-maven-plugin` to spit out certain Kotlin classes as JavaScript:

```
    <configuration>
        <outputFile>${project.basedir}/angular/src/assets/kotlin_classes.js</outputFile>
        <moduleKind>commonjs</moduleKind>
    </configuration>
```

With a Kotlin class that looks like:

```
class SomeKotlinClass {
    fun someMethod(name: String): String {
        return "Happy Birthday, " + name;
    }
}
```

The problem that we're encountering is that no matter what `moduleKind` we use (we've tried `plain`, `umd`, `amd`), our method names seem to have an odd/garbled suffix in the JavaScript file:

```
  SomeKotlinClass.prototype.someMethod_6q3v0v$ = function (name) {
    return 'Happy Birthday, ' + name
  };
```

This means that our calls in Angular/TypeScript can't be to `someMethod()`, they have to be to `someMethod_6q3v0v$()`, which doesn't work for us.

Am I doing something wrong with my plugin configuration, or with the way I'm including this JavaScript file in our project? We're 99% of the way there, but this last (strange) hurdle is holding us up.

Comment: The @JsName annotation should solve your immediate issue. However there are many other issues, as described in my blog post [building-applications-with-kotlin-and-typescript](https://medium.com/@dr.david.h.akehurst/building-applications-with-kotlin-and-typescript-8a165e76252c).
such as:
- using kotlin types
- generating .d.ts files
- getting the kotlin generated code into the node_modules directory (or assets)

I would be interested how you solved those issues yourself?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the compiled method in Javascript can be set using the `@JSName(...)` annotation.

In this case:

```
class SomeKotlinClass {
    @JsName("someMethod")
    fun someMethod(name: String): String {
        return "Happy Birthday, " + name;
    }
}
```

Which then is compiled to:

```
SomeKotlinClass.prototype.someMethod = function (name) {
   return 'Happy Birthday, ' + name;
};
```